# How to monitor where a program connects to on the Internet through a router

Tags: networking, display, connection

I know everyone is saying to use TCPview or Wireshark, etc., but what I want to ask is how to do it over router connection, because all the remote addresses for the programs are going to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is your own machine (localhost). So those connections aren't really going anywhere. What in particular are you concerned with?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is your localhost ( i.e. ) the local computer.  Downvote for lack effort to ask a well researched question.

Comment: Calm down guys, the question is not that bad; it is due to confusion about the remote/local label.

Answer (score 0):

When the remote address is 127.0.0.1 (the [localhost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)/[loopback address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback)), it is actually an **incoming** connection to your system. What you need to look at is the *local address* for those connections to see where they are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question a few years ago, Googling this answered it for me. It was something with adding a loopback adapter to the network connections or something... Think it shouldn't be that hard to find. I probably googled for something like "capture traffic from loopback adapter" or "capturing wireshark 127.0.0.1" or something.

I'll edit if I find something. If not, hope this helped you to find a solution!

Edit: First hit on Google gave me this: http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback